# Why does my if statement return greater than 1 when there's only one element selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Why my "more than 1 system" appear with only one .system, :

as you can see in codepen when I drag and drop 1 `class="systeme"` into `#dz` , the "more than 1 system " appear but it shouldnt because its not

`$("#dz").find(".systeme").length >= 1`

but

`$("#dz").find(".systeme").length > 1`

```
$("#dz").droppable({
    accept: ".systeme",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
         $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#dz"));
         if ($("#dz").find(".systeme").length > 1) {
             $("#docs").html("<li>more than 1 system</li>");
         }
    }
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Cyril29/pen/dybLaam)

Thks

Comment: Hi, Welcome, can you better explain the problem you facing? explain in detail the issue, i cannot understand the problem correctly. thanks.

Comment: as you can see in codepen when i drag and drop 1 <li class="systeme" into #dz , the " <li>more than 1 system</li>  " appear but it shouldnt because its not $("#dz").find(".systeme").length >= 1 but $("#dz").find(".systeme").length > 1

Comment: Please put that information in your post. Don't expect your volunteer helpers to scour comments for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would like "more than 1 system" to appear more than once, if so, change

```js
$("#docs").html("<li>more than 1 system</li>");
```

by

```js
var li=document.createElement("LI");
li.innerHTML="more than 1 system";
$("#docs").append(li);
```

I correct, What you are looking for is in the conditional

change

```js
if ($("#dz").find(".systeme").length > 1)
```

by

```js
if ($("#dz").find(".systeme").length - 1 > 1)
```

Other

```js
if ($("#dz").find(".systeme").length > 1) {
   $("#docs").html("<li>more than 1 system</li>");
}
```

by

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    if ($("#dz").find(".systeme").length > 1) {
        $("#docs").html("<li>more than 1 system</li>");
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Can you explain why that's necessary? That's the point of confusion.

Comment: if you type $("#dz").find(".systeme").length in console result is "0"

Comment: Because when counting the children of #dz, it counts the element with "+", so by adding the first .length it returned 2, not 1

Comment: it doesnt count children of #dz but children with .systeme class. You can try without "+" its same problem

Comment: That is why, when you temporarily release an item, you clone it and then remove it, so always give one more when you count them. I add another way to solve it, you must tell it shortly after the process is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this condition : `if ($("#dz").find(".systeme").length > 1)`

if you change this part you can append as much you want playing with length element condition.

check my example. please open it full page

```
$("#dz").droppable({
                accept: ".systeme",
                drop: function(e, ui) {

                    $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#dz"));
                    $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#docs"));

                }
            });
```

```js
$(function() {

  $(".systeme").draggable({
    appendTo: '#dz',
    cursor: 'move',
    revertDuration: 400,
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone'
  });

  $("#dz").droppable({
    accept: ".systeme",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#dz"));
      $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($("#docs"));
      if ($("#dz").find(".systeme").length > 3) {
        $("#docs").html("<li>more than 1 system</li>");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.num {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#add {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.colonne {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 2%;
}

.colonnes:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-style: dotted;
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="colonnes">
  <div class="colonne" id="colonne G">
    <h2>systèmes</h2>
    <ul>
      <li class="systeme visioimt">Terminal de Visio local</li>
      <li class="systeme pc">PC</li>
      <li class="systeme tel">Téléphone</li>
      <li class="systeme android">Android</li>
      <li class="systeme visioext">Terminal de Visio Exterieur</li>
      <li class="systeme skype">Skype</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="colonne" id="colonne D">
    <h2>sites</h2>
    <ul id="dz">
      <li id="add">+</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <br>

</div>
<div>
  <h2>docs</h2>
  <ul id="docs">
  </ul>
</div>
```